# AngularJS - Parse route and redirect

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to integrate a live site to be mobile friendly. Is there a way in AngularJS to take in a url e.g. ../15K6#colors and route it to the mobile routes which should be ../colors/15K6

I am looking into $routeProvider, but am still new to Angular. Any help would be appreciated!

Below is a snippet of my config block with $routeProvider

```
    .config(
    [ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/models', {
            templateUrl : 'views/models/models.html'
        }).when('/models/:modelCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/models/model-detail.html'
        }).when('/colors/:modelCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/colors/colors.html'
        }).when('/packages/:modelCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/packages/packages.html'
        }).when('/packages/:modelCode/package-detail/:optionCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/packages/package-detail.html'
        }).when('/options/:modelCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/options/options.html'
        }).when('/accessories/:modelCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/accessories/accessories.html'
        }).when('/accessories/:modelCode/accessory-options/:groupName', {
            templateUrl : 'views/accessories/accessory-options.html'
        }).when('/summary/:modelCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/summary/summary.html'
        }).when('/disclaimer/:modelCode', {
            templateUrl : 'views/disclaimer/disclaimer.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/models'
            //  parse url for deep linking
            //  e.g.    ../15K6#colors into colors/15K6
        });
    } ]
```

Comment: why are your mobile routes using a different scheme anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Better if you provide more code details what you have so far.

On top of my head i can tell that you to have pass the `$location` param when you define the controller.

```
myApp.module('MyController', function($scope, $location){
     $location.path("url");
})
```

Or in the route path just ask for the mobile template instead of the desktop template